# assigned delegate, but function is not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Hi guys i would want to fire a method in SecondViewController from FirstViewController when the condition is meet. So i have used delegate to do so and my code is as follow:

FirstViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import Foundation

class BluetoothViewController: UIViewController, ValueChangedDelegate {


if (characteristic.UUID == CBUUID(string: "2AF0")){
        DataReceived.Single_Axis = Double(CharValue)


func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
        let singleaxisview = SingeAxisViewController()
        singleaxisview.delegate = self
        singleaxisview.valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
        println("btfired")
    }
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

protocol ValueChangedDelegate
{
    func valueChanged(nValue : String)
}

class SingeAxisViewController: UIViewController {


var delegate : ValueChangedDelegate?


func valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
{
        println("hello")
    delegate?.valueChanged("changed value")
}
```

Can somebody point out to me what i missed?

Comment: Where do you initialize the `BTController` variable?

Comment: at secondViewController line above ViewDidLoad Function

Comment: It is not the initialization, `BTController` still nil. I bet your code will crash at `BTController!.delegate = self` because you are trying to unwrap a nil variable.

Comment: Have you set the second SecondViewController object as the delegate of the FirstViewController?

Comment: @t4nhpt oh, my code crash. By the way how can i initialise BTController?

Comment: Today, I saw 2 or 3 questions about call an action of a view controller from another one. And the mistake is they always create new `first view controller` instance. In fact, the first view controller show the second view controller, and we must use the existed `first view controller`, should not re-create it. Can you tell me, how your `second view controller` is shown?

Comment: By Segue from Main.Storyboard with  button click on firstViewController
My aim is to fire a function under SecondViewController when value in FirstViewController Changed My FirstViewController is CoreBluetooth delegate by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `BTController!.delegate = self` you will have to use object of FirstViewController and set the delegate and you will also need to initialise the FirstViewController object. here is a sample code if you want to implement it. the first view controller implements the delegate methods and on call of btnClicked the second view controller is called and you get the response back to first view controller in  the valueChanged method

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, ValueChangedDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        lbl.text = "inital value"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!


    @IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.delegate = self
        secondViewController.valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
    }



    func valueChanged(nValue : String)
    {
        print(nValue)
        lbl.text = nValue
    }


}
```

Second view controller which implements the protocol and the also calls the protocol method from valueChangedNotifyEveryone method

```
import UIKit


protocol ValueChangedDelegate
{
    func valueChanged(nValue : String)
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    var delegate : ValueChangedDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func valueChangedNotifyEveryone()
    {

        delegate?.valueChanged("changed value")
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Unfortunately i would get error with the codes.
1. FirstViewController doesn't conform to protocol ValueChanged
2. singleaxisview.delegate = self cannot assign a value of type 'FirstViewController to a type "ValueChanged"

Comment: 1. FirstViewController doesn't conform to protocol ValueChanged 2. singleaxisview.delegate = self cannot assign a value of type 'FirstViewController to a type "ValueChanged"

Comment: 1. In FirstViewController you haven't implement the delegate methods of ValueChanged 2. If you can post the entire code i can help you

Comment: You will need to implement this method in your BluetoothViewController func valueChanged(nValue : String)
    {
        print(nValue)
    }

Comment: that is the method through which you would get the callBack. Did it work?

Comment: Oh, i just make a careless mistake! i got it working now! Thank you very much!!